# Hibernate ignores @AttributeOverrides annotation and creates columns in a wrong table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping

I have 2 SQL tables:

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('global_seq'),

    /* email, password, other fields */

);
```

Users_avatars:

```
CREATE TABLE users_avatars
(
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    file_name VARCHAR,
    file_path VARCHAR,

    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
);
```

However, why I try to map it with Hibernate it creates `file_name` and `file_path` inside the `users` table.

My classes are the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@SecondaryTable(name = "users_avatars",
        pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
public class User extends EntityWithId
{
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "file_name", column = @Column(table = "users_avatars")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "file_path", column = @Column(table = "users_avatars"))
    })
    private FileInDb avatar;


    public FileInDb getAvatar()
    {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(FileInDb avatar)
    {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }
}
```

And FileInDb class:

```
@Embeddable
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class FileInDb
{
    @Column(name = "file_name")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String fileName;

    @Column(name = "file_path")
    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String filePath;

    public String getFileName()
    {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFilePath()
    {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }
}
```

SQL script generated by Hibernate:

```
create table users (
   id int8 not null,
    file_name varchar(255),
    file_path varchar(255),
    /* Lots of other fields */
    primary key (id)
)
create table users_avatars (
   user_id int8 not null,
    primary key (user_id)
)
```

Why is so? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to have two tables, you should use the `@OneToOne` mapping: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one
`@Embedded` works only if you want to have columns from `@Embeddable` in parent table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do this since `@OneToOne` requires both parties to be Entities. I don't want FileInDb to be one, mainly because it requires to have ID

Comment: Why is this a problem? Always you can to create new class and extends with `FileInDb` (or use `FileInDb` as embeddable class). Then you can set this class as `@Entity`.

Comment: Because it shouldn't have ID, ID always comes from the "outside" (foreign key)

Comment: You can put an `@Id @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") @OneToOne User owner` property in `FileInDb` as its `id`, and then `user_id` will become its ID. No need for a separate technical ID property

Comment: I think it is problem with `AttributeOverrides`. `name` should be as field property from embeddable class and in `@Column` annotation you should add real column name besides table name. Additioanally @Mappedsuperclass is not needed acording to hibernate docs: `You can define @AttributeOverride(s) and @AssociationOverride(s) on @Entity classes, @MappedSuperclass classes and properties pointing to an @Embeddable object.`. Not sure though if this is the real solution.

Comment: @crizzis, the problem is that it can be used with pretty much any entity, not only `user`

Comment: In that case, the easiest solution will be to use an `@ElementCollection` of `FileInDb`s

Comment: @crizzis, yes it works, however, violates the rules of the model architecture

Answer (score 0):

You can use @OneToOne mapping with @MapsId to use the user_id as the id field for the user_avatars table

Comment: Not a general solution, because I expect `FileInDb` work with other entities as well, besides `user`

Comment: The Embeddable is your answer, however it has its own way of working. In JPA, an embeddable entity is meant to be EMBEDDED into another entity that has a Table declaration. Apart from that, your problem requires a OneToOne mapping, the fact that it is referenced in other tables using a foreign key doesn’t compromise the solution in anyway except for an additional JOIN statement to your query. RDBMSes don’t fall apart from a single JOIN statement unless the table design is fundamentally bad